# How to deal with constants on computer simulations?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, simulations, physical-constants

I'm beggining learning about natural simulations on my courses and I had a few questions about time, and especially with the game "Universe Sandox²". I know about the basic Newton's formulas about gravitation and so... And I was wondering how to deal with units and real time on computer simulations. Firstly, the computer and "game loop" run at a specific frame rate (ex 60 FPS). So how can we get real simulation seconds?

Secondly, what constants should we use, because the computer screen is measured in pixels and not in meters. For example, how does Universe Sandbox² keep the real "Gravitational constant G" even if the software must use pixels to represent the simulation?

In fact, I'm a bit confused of on what domain are these constants available? I watched many programs and tutorials but most of them just use a random value which **seems** to be "legit" and "accurate". But I want to keep the real value so how to do that?

Comment: The answer depends on the user and the designer of the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map linearly from pixels to real-world distance units. For example, if you are doing a solar system simulation out to Pluto, you might want it to cover a square 15 trillion meters on a side since the maxiumum orbital radius of Pluto is 7.4 billion kilometers. If you’re using a 3000x3000 piece of the screen to render this simulation, then each pixel represents 5 billion meters.

On the other hand, watching a real-time simulation of the solar system would be pretty boring! Pluto takes 248 years to go around the Sun. This kind of thing is why the time scale of simulations is often sped up or slowed down, depending on whether the simulated system is much larger or much smaller than things we experience in everyday life.

Comment: So just a simple rule of three? And yep, but if you have the real-times equations, you just need to apply a simple product to speed up time!

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t understand what you mean by “rule of three”.

Comment: Well didn't found the name of that in English!
simply, if 3 seconds on simulation => 1 seconds on real time,
              4 seconds on simulation => 4*1/3 seconds on real time

Comment: Yes, that’s right. I call it a linear mapping. You just use proportions.

Comment: Allright, so to conclude, we just need to convert pixels and program-based-time-units into real values by simply using linear mapping!

Comment: Would you like to mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: That's done, sorry, I'm new to this forum x). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and you’re welcome. I think some people downvoted your question because it’s more about programming than about physics. We try to keep the focus on physics in this forum.

Comment: I know but on the forum about programming, people downvoted my question because they said it was about physics ^^'. But that's the way it is!